# What is the solution to $ax^{2} - bxc^{\frac{1}{x}}+dc^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0$?

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to solve

$$ax^{2} - bxc^{\frac{1}{x}}+dc^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0.$$

However, I'm apparently doing a silly mistake in the following procedure.
May someone tell me what is wrong here?

---

By applying logarithm operator to the equation, one has

$$\log{a} + 2\log{x} - \log{b} - \log{x} - \frac{1}{x}\log{c} + \log{d} + \frac{1}{x}\log{c} = 0,$$

which simplifies to

$$\log{\frac{ad}{b}} = - \log{x},$$

thereby

$$x = \frac{b}{ad}.$$

Comment: @antonzm found your mistake. This equation does not have a nice solution. I think you will have to sovle it numerically for particular values of the constants.

Comment: In general, $\log(x+y)\neq\log(x)+\log(y)$.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Is this a transcendental equation?

Comment: I could “simplify” the equation to $$ xln|\frac{ax^2}{bx-d}|=ln|c|$$. I don’t know what else to do after this.

Comment: @Pinton Yes, Knowing that name won't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in that $log(a+b)\neq log(a)+log(b)$, plus that $log(0)$ is not well defined.